# Mapping python tuple and R list with rpy2?

Tags: python, r, mapping, tuples, rpy2

I'm having some trouble to understand the mapping with rpy2 object and python object.

I have a function(x) which return a tuple object in python, and i want to map this tuple object with R object list or vector.

**First, i'm trying to do this :**

```
# return a python tuple into this r object tlist
robjects.r.tlist = get_max_ticks(x) 

#Convert list into dataframe
r('x <- as.data.frame(tlist,row.names=c("seed","ticks"))')
```

FAIL with error :
 rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'tlist' not found

**So i'm trying an other strategy :**

```
robjects.r["tlist"]  = get_max_ticks(x)
r('x <- as.data.frame(tlist,row.names=c("seed","ticks"))')
```

FAIL with this error :
TypeError: 'R' object does not support item assignment

Could you help me to understand ?
Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 3):

Use `globalEnv`:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
r=ro.r

def get_max_ticks():
    return (1,2)
ro.globalEnv['tlist'] = ro.FloatVector(get_max_ticks())
r('x <- as.data.frame(tlist,row.names=c("seed","ticks"))')
print(r['x'])
#       tlist
# seed      1
# ticks     2
```

It may be possible to access symbols in the `R` namespace with this type of notation: `robjects.r.tlist`, but you can not assign values this way. The way to assign symbol is to use `robject.globalEnv`.

Moreover, some symbols in `R` may contain a period, such as `data.frame`. You can not access such symbols in Python using notation similar to `robjects.r.data.frame`, since Python interprets the period differently than `R`. So I'd suggest avoiding this notation entirely, and instead use
`robjects.r['data.frame']`, since this notation works no matter what the symbol name is.

Comment: This notation is not safe either, as doing something like "ro.globalEnv['data.frame'] = ro.r('function(x) NULL')" somewhere before will cause problem.

I recommend using the class DataFrame.

Comment: Thx @~unutbu, thx @lgautier for your response here and on mailling list, now i'm trying to understand example with data.frame object in manual

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid the assignment in R all together:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
tlist = ro.FloatVector((1,2))
keyWordArgs = {'row.names':ro.StrVector(("seed","ticks"))}
x = ro.r['as.data.frame'](tlist,**keyWordArgs)
ro.r['print'](x)
```